# Text clustering using arbitrary metrics with sklearn kmeans

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, cosine-similarity

I'm running text clustering on a table that contains medical terms, I want to cluster strings that have similar words, if two have have two words or more, should be included in one cluster more likely than if they only have one word in common.

I tried many techniques and I'm not getting any efficient results! I tried first using Levenshtein distance with both kmeans and AgglomerativeClustering( three linkage methods: ward, complete and avaerage). It returns poor results and this metric combined words having partially similar letters, like " dog" and " door".

I changed the distance metric into using TF-IDF and then run cosine similarity, and then I converted the similarity to distance by subtract each value by 1 ( distance = 1- similarity), cause I tried the wiki method by 2* acosine(similarity) and it returned nan values!

Anyway, with this distance metric, I tried also both algorithms, It return good clusters overall, except one huge one that don't contain similar words between them! no matter how I change the value of no of clusters, this huge cluster will still appear even If I choose large no of k ( close to n which is the length of input), and it's usually appearing in the beginning, either cluster 0, 1, 2, 3.. Why this is happening?? what I'm doing wrong? my dataset length is more than 5000. and this is part of the clusters output.

```
 cluster no 0:['Prolonged INR', 'Prolonged PTT', 'Prolonged QT Interval']
 cluster no 1:['GI bleeding', 'Gastrointestinal (GI) Bleeding', 'Lower GI bleeding']
 cluster no 2:['ACS', 'Acetazolamide', 'Achondroplasia', 'Acrocyanosis', 'Acromegaly', 'Adenoidectomy', 'Adenomyosis', 'Afebrile', 'Antihistamine', 'Apheresis', 'Aplasia', 'Argatroban', 'Arthralgia', 'Arthrocentesis', 'Arthrography', 'Arthroplasty', 'Asbestosis', 'Ascorbate', 'Asian', 'Asterixis', 'Astigmatism', 'Astrocytoma', 'Asymptomatic', 'Atelectasis', 'Atherosclerosis', 'Atropine', 'Audiogram', 'Autonomic Dysreflexia', 'Autopsy', 'Bacteremia', 'Balanitis', 'Balanoposthitis', 'Breastfeeding', 'Breech Presentation', 'Bronchiectasis', 'Bronchiolitis', 'Bronchospasm', 'Cachexia', 'Cafï¿½ Au Lait Spot', 'Calcaneovalgus', 'Chalazion', 'Chemistry Panels', 'Chills', 'Cholelithiasis', 'Cholera', 'Chondroblastoma', 'Chondrosarcoma', 'Chorioamnionitis', 'Chorionic Villus Sampling (CVS)', 'Choroid Plexus Papilloma (CPP)', 'Circumcision', 'Citrate', 'Claudication', 'Clonus', 'Coccidioidomycosis', 'Coccygodynia', 'Costochondritis', 'Craniectomy', 'Craniofacial Anomalies', 'Craniopharyngioma', 'Craniosynostosis', 'Craniotomy', 'Cri du Chat', 'Croup', 'Cryofibrinogen', 'Cryoglobulin', 'Cyclophosphamide', 'Cystometry', 'D-Dimer', 'Dacryocystitis', 'Dacryocystorhinostomy (DCR)', 'Dacryostenosis', 'Dantrolene', 'Deformational Plagiocephaly', 'Delusions', 'Demeclocycline', 'Dentures', 'Dermabrasion', 'Deviated Septum', 'Electrolytes', 'Electronystagmography (ENG)', 'Embolectomy', 'Emmetropia', 'Empyema', 'Enchondroma', 'Encopresis', 'Enterovirus', 'Ependymoma', 'Epididymitis', 'Epirubicin', 'Episiotomy', 'Epispadias', 'Eribulin', 'Erythroderma', 'Esophagectomy', 'Essential Tremor', 'Foraminotomy', 'Frostnip/Frostbite', 'Gallstones', 'Gastritis', 'Gastrojejunostomy', 'Gastroschisis', 'Giardiasis', 'Gingivitis', 'Gingivostomatitis', 'Glaucoma', 'Gliomas', 'Glomerulonephritis', 'Glomerulosclerosis', 'Group B Streptococcus', 'Herpangina', 'Hiccups', 'Hidradenitis Suppurativa', 'Hirsutism', 'Hookworm', 'Hordeolum (Stye)', 'Hydatidiform Mole', 'Hydration', 'Hydrocelectomy', 'Hydrops Fetalis', 'Hyperbilirubinemia', 'Hyperlipidemia', 'Hyperopia', 'Hyperphosphatemia', 'Hyperreflexia', 'Hypnosis', 'Hypoparathyroidism', 'Hypopituitarism', 'Hypovolemia', 'Hypoxia', 'Hysterosalpingogram (HSG)', 'Hysteroscopy', 'Intussusception', 'Irritability', 'Isoproterenol', 'Ixabepilone', 'Jewish', 'Karyotype', 'Keratoconus', 'Ketonemia', 'Ketonuria', 'Kyphoplasty', 'Kyphosis', 'Labyrinthitis', 'Lactulose', 'Laminectomy', 'Laminotomy', 'Lapatinib', 'Laryngectomy', 'Laryngitis', 'Laryngomalacia', 'Laryngoscopy', 'Laxative', 'Lymphadenitis', 'Lymphangitis', 'Lymphocele', 'Malaise', 'Malaria', 'Malocclusion', 'Mammography', 'Mannitol', 'Mastalgia', 'Mastectomy', 'Mastitis', 'Mastoidectomy', 'Mastopexy', 'Mediastinoscopy', 'Megaureter', 'Melena', 'Meningioma', 'Menopause', 'Menorrhagia', 'Menstruation', 'Metatarsalgia', 'Metatarsus Adductus', 'Metoclopramide', 'Neomycin', 'Nephrectomy', 'Nephrolithiasis', 'Neuromyelitis Optica', 'Neurosonography', 'Neurosurgery', 'Nocturnal Enuresis', 'Norovirus', 'Pericardectomy', 'Perimenopause', 'Periventricular Leukomalacia', 'Pertuzumab', 'Phimosis', 'Phobia', 'Photorefractive Keratectomy (PRK)', 'Phytophotodermatitis', 'Pilomatrixoma', 'Pinworms', 'Pityriasis Rosea', 'Plain radiograph', 'Platelets', 'Pleurisy', 'Pneumococcus', 'Pneumoconiosis', 'Pneumonectomy', 'Psychosis', 'Pterygium', 'Ptosis', 'Pulpitis (Toothache)', 'Pyeloplasty', 'Quantitative Immunoglobulins', 'Rabies', 'Rales', 'Red wale marks', 'Refractive Error', 'Smallpox', 'Smoking Cessation', 'Snoring', 'Sonohysterography', 'Spasmodic Dysphonia', 'Spina Bifida', 'Terlipressin', 'Tetany', 'Thoracotomy', 'Thrombocythemia', 'Thrombophilia', 'Thrombophlebitis', 'Thyroidectomy', 'Tinnitus', 'Tonsillar enlargement', 'Torn Annulus', 'Toxoplasmosis', 'Trabeculectomy', 'Ureterolysis', 'Ureteroplasty', 'Ureterosigmoidostomy', 'Urethritis', 'Urethroplasty', 'Uroflowmetry', 'Urostomy', 'Urticaria (Hives)', 'Uvulitis', 'Uvulopalatopharyngoplasty (UPPP)', 'Valsalva Maneuver', 'Varicella (Chickenpox)', 'Vasculitis', 'Vasopressin', 'Vasopressor', 'Venography', 'Ventriculostomy', 'Vertebroplasty', 'Vesicoureteral Reflux (VUR)', 'Osteochondritis Dissecans (OCD)', 'Osteochondroma', 'Osteogenesis Imperfecta (OI)', 'Osteopenia', 'Osteophyte formation', 'Osteosarcoma', 'Overuse Injuries', 'Overweight', 'Pallister Killian', 'Pallor', 'Palpitation', 'Palpitations', 'Paraesthesia', 'Paranoia', 'Paraphimosis', 'Parasomnias', 'Parathyroidectomy', 'Paronychia', 'Parotidectomy', 'Peaked T waves', 'Pemphigus Vulgaris', 'Lepirudin', 'Lethargy', 'Letrozole', 'Lichen Planus', 'Liposarcoma', 'Listeriosis', 'Living will', 'Lordosis', 'Excessive urination', 'Exemestane', 'Exploratory Laparotomy', 'Facelift (Rhytidectomy)', 'Fainting', 'Fibrinogen', 'Fibromyalgia', 'Fluorouracil', 'Folliculitis', 'Fondaparinux', 'Bedbound', 'Bedrest', 'Bevacizumab', 'BiPAP', 'Biloma', 'Birthmark', 'Bisphosphonate', 'Bivalirudin', 'Blepharitis', 'Blepharoplasty', 'Blindness', 'Blister', 'Bloodborne Pathogens', 'Allopurinol', 'Alopecia', 'Amblyopia', 'Amenorrhea', 'Amniocentesis', 'Anastrozole', 'Anencephaly', 'Angiodysplasia', 'Angioembolization', 'Ankyloglossia', 'Ankylosing Spondylitis', 'Haptoglobin', 'HbA1C', 'Heatstroke', 'Height', 'Heliox', 'Hematemesis', 'Hematochezia', 'Hematocrit', 'Hematology', 'Hemifacial Microsomia', 'Hemochromatosis', 'Hemoglobinuria', 'Hemophagocytic Lymphohistiocytosis (HLH)', 'Hemothorax', 'Hepatoblastoma', 'Hepatomegaly', 'Hepatosplenomegaly', 'Hepatotoxicity', 'Her2neu', 'IgG Deficiencies', 'Ileostomy', 'Impetigo', 'Improving', 'Impulsiveness', 'Incontinentia Pigmenti', 'Restlessness', 'Retinitis Pigmentosa', 'Retinoblastoma', 'Reversible Dementias', 'Rhabdomyosarcoma', 'Rhinoplasty', 'Rifaximin', 'Rosacea', 'Roseola', 'STEMI', 'Sacroiliitis', 'Scabies', 'Schistocytes', 'Sciatica', 'Scleral Buckling', 'Scleroderma', 'Sclerotherapy', 'Scotoma', 'Selective Mutism', 'Digitalization', 'Dihydroergotamine', 'Discogram', 'Dislocations', 'Disorientation', 'Diverticulosis', 'Docetaxel', 'Domperidone', 'Dopamine', 'Doxorubicin', 'Drooling', 'Drowsiness', 'Duodenitis', "Dupuytren's Contracture", 'Dyskeratosis Congenita', 'Dyslipidemia', 'Dysmenorrhea', 'Dysphasia', 'Dyssomnias', 'Dysthymia', 'Dysuria', 'ESR', 'Eclampsia', 'Ectropion (Eublepharon)', 'Ehrlichiosis', 'Translocations', 'Transverse Myelitis', 'Trastuzumab', 'Trigeminal Neuralgia', 'Tympanoplasty', 'Unconscious', 'Underweight', 'Undescended Testes (Cryptorchidism)', 'Ureter obstructed', 'Colchicine', 'Coldness', 'Colectomy', 'Coloboma', 'Colostomy', 'Colposcopy', 'Comfort Measures Only (CMO)', 'Comorbid conditions', 'Compromised local circulation', 'Conivaptan', 'Constipation', 'Continence', 'Cor Pulmonale', 'Splinters', 'Spondylolisthesis', 'Spondylolysis', 'Stapedectomy', 'Steroid', 'Stillbirth', 'Stomatitis', 'Strabismus (Crossed Eyes)', 'Stridor', 'Stupor', 'Suicide plan', 'Sunburn', 'Suprasternal retractions', 'Sympathectomy', 'Tapeworm', 'Tattoo', 'Tau/A Beta42', 'Teething', 'Telangiectasias', 'Temper Tantrum', 'Temporal Arteritis', 'Microbiology', 'Microcephaly', 'Microdiskectomy', 'Micropenis', 'Midodrine', 'Miscarriage', 'Modified duke criteria', 'Molluscum Contagiosum', 'Monoamniotic twins', 'Mosaicism', 'Motorcycle accident', 'Myalgias', 'Myasthenia Gravis', 'Myelogram', 'Myoclonus', 'Myoglobinuria', 'Myopia', 'Myositis', 'Myxedema', 'NSAID', 'Narcolepsy', 'Nausea', 'Poliomyelitis', 'Poly-pharmacy', 'Polyhydramnios (Hydramnios)', 'Polymyalgia Rheumatica', 'Polymyositis', 'Postictal State', 'Presbycusis', 'Presbyopia', 'Presyncope', 'Proctectomy', 'Proctocolectomy', 'Pruritis Ani', 'Pseudotumor Cerebri', 'Vinorelbine', 'Vitrectomy', 'Voiding Cystourethrogram (VCUG)', 'Vomit', 'Vulvitis', "Wegener's Granulomatosis", 'Whiplash', 'Widening QRS', 'Wrinkles', 'X-linked Agammaglobulinemia', 'YAG Capsulotomy', 'Yersiniosis', 'caffeine', 'coagulopathy', 'dexamethasone', 'Infliximab', 'Insomnia', 'Insulinoma', 'Intravenous contrast extravasation', 'Obtundation', 'Octreotide', 'Odynophagia', 'Oligodendroglioma', 'Oligohydramnios', 'Oliguria', 'Omphalocele', 'Onychomycosis', 'Oophorectomy', 'Orchiectomy', 'Orchitis', 'Orthopnea', 'Carboplatin', 'Cardiomegaly', 'Cataracts', 'Cecostomy', 'Cephalopelvic Disproportion (CPD)']
 cluster no 3:['Brain Malignancy', 'Brain metastasis']
 cluster no 4:['Pubic Lice', 'Lice', 'Head Lice']
 cluster no 5:['Assistive, Adaptive, Supportive or Protective Device Fitting', 'Gait Training Using an Assistive Device', 'Unsteady gait']
 cluster no 6:['Removal of Soft Tissue Foreign Body', 'Soft Tissue Foreign Body']
 cluster no 7:['Necrotizing pneumonia', 'Pneumocystis Pneumonia', 'Pneumocystis pneumonia', 'Pneumonia', 'Pneumonia', 'Mycoplasma Pneumonia', 'Walking Pneumonia']
 cluster no 8:['Esophageal Atresia', 'Esophageal Dilation', 'Esophageal Manometry', 'Esophageal ring/web', 'Esophageal stricture']
```

What am I doing wrong? Are my techniques are wrong here?
Here is my code, I change to other techniques easily using sklearn packages,:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import pprint

my_list = ['Cervical Cryotherapy', 'Cervical Disk Replacement Surgery', 'Cervical Disk Rupture', 'Cervical Disk Surgery', 'Cervical Epidural Injection', 'Cervical Fracture (exclude uncomplicated compression fractures)', 'Cervical Insufficiency (Cervical Incompetence)', 'Cervical Neck Brace', 'Cervical Radiculopathy', 'Cervical Spinal Fusion', 'Cervical Spine Disorder', 'Cervical Spondylosis', 'Cervical Subluxation', 'Cervical dilation', 'Cervical dislocation', 'Cervical effacement', 'Cervical ripening procedure', 'Cervicitis', 'Cervicitis (Non-STD)', 'Cervicitis (STD)', 'Cervix', 'Cervix closed', 'Cesarean Section (C-Section)', 'Cesarean section procedure', 'Chagas Disease']

tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)
#print (tfidf_matrix.shape)

k=len(my_list)
dist = np.zeros((k,k))

for i in range(k):
       dist[i] = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[i:i+1], tfidf_matrix)
#print(dist

dist1 = np.subtract(np.ones((k,k),dtype=np.float), dist) ## convert to distance
#print(dist1)

data2=np.asarray(dist1)
arr_3d = data2.reshape((1,k,k))

#print(arr_3d)


for i in range(len(arr_3d)):

  km = KMeans(n_clusters=5, init='k-means++')
  km = km.fit(arr_3d[i])

  centers = km.cluster_centers_
  labels = km.labels_

  print (labels)
  print(type(labels))

Groups = {}
for element, label in zip(my_list, labels):
    print 'element', element
    print 'label', label

    try:
        Groups[str(label)].append(element)
    except:
        Groups[str(label)] = [element]

pprint.pprint(Groups)
```

EDIT:
I'm using now only cosine similarity, and getting the same problem, big cluster with unrelated words, so it's not tf-idf problem!

```
    WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')

    def get_cosine(vec1, vec2):
         intersection = set(vec1.keys()) & set(vec2.keys())
         numerator = sum([vec1[x] * vec2[x] for x in intersection])

         sum1 = sum([vec1[x]**2 for x in vec1.keys()])
         sum2 = sum([vec2[x]**2 for x in vec2.keys()])
         denominator = math.sqrt(sum1) * math.sqrt(sum2)

         if not denominator:
            return 0.0
         else:
            return float(numerator) / denominator

    def text_to_vector(text):
         words = WORD.findall(text)
         return Counter(words)


k=len(my_list)

data1 = np.zeros((k,k))

for i,string1 in enumerate(my_list):
   for j,string2 in enumerate(my_list):
        data1[i][j] = 1-get_cosine(text_to_vector(string1), text_to_vector(string2))

print(data1)
k=len(my_list)
data2=np.asarray(data1)
arr_3d = data2.reshape((1,k,k))
```

Edit: I run LSA instead of TF-IDF which should be suitable for short text, but I got very very bad results! clusters that don't match:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df = 1, stop_words = 'english')
dtm = vectorizer.fit_transform(my_list)

lsa = TruncatedSVD(2, algorithm = 'arpack')
dtm_lsa = lsa.fit_transform(dtm)
dtm_lsa = Normalizer(copy=False).fit_transform(dtm_lsa)
similarity = np.asarray(numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa) * numpy.asmatrix(dtm_lsa).T)
#print(1-similarity)
k=len(my_list)
dist1 = np.subtract(np.ones((k,k),dtype=np.float), similarity)
#dist1.astype(float)
print(dist1)
```

Comment: Not sure why the -1 to the question seriously !!!!!!

Comment: I fixed your example to print your result a bit better, and removed all unrequited imports. Now its easy to understand your problem :)

Comment: Thanks, any ideas about the problem?

Comment: One big cluster is most probably feature extraction fail: documents, that have no features extracted, are very similar, _in fact its exact duplicates))_

Comment: Haha - is it possible I fixed your problem in the print statement at the end? Perhaps it was an array manipulation error, instead of a clustering error?

Comment: @D adams, unfortunately no :(( I'm still having the same problem

Comment: @Lol4t0, can you explain more please? and how to fix that'/

Comment: @Lol4t0, the big cluster doesn't have duplicated, it has unrelated strings to each other 
cluster no 2:['ACS', 'Acetazolamide', 'Achondroplasia', 'Acrocyanosis', 'Acromegaly',

Comment: You clustetize not documents, but features. Think the difference. Your feature table is tfdif matrix. Make sure it has no rows that contain only zeros. Rows of only zeros a similar for clustering algorithm regardless of documents that those rows denote

Comment: @Lol4t0.. I tried to print tfdif matrix but didn't find zeros. However, not sure where is the problem! Do I need to avoid using tfdif?

Comment: I see what you are saying now, what is the solution for this? any suggestions? @Lol4t0

Comment: Configure TFIDF - set up proper min_df & max_df, proper stemmer, provide stopword list

Comment: Can you explain more about those? as an answer

Comment: How to avoid those unsimilar words grouping together?

Comment: @Lol4t0, see the edit

Comment: This is a very typical k-means result. K-means is **sensitive to noise**. If you look at the cluster sizes, you probably have mostly tiny clusters (duplicates and near-duplicates) and then one huge cluster with the remainders (can you add cluster sizes to your question?). Typical k-means result.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, this happens also when I use heighracial clustering with all the types of linkage, what I can do?

Comment: I don't think that data can be clustered *at all* without massive language models (Google scale).

Comment: You mean doc2vec?? I searched about it and it has the same idea as TF-IDF

Comment: I want to use LSA instead of TF-IDF, but not sure how to start, any help plz?

Comment: I used LSA and it returns very bad clusters!!

Answer (score 1):

k-means is based on **variance minimization**.

It minimizes the **sum of squared deviations**, `(x[i]-center[i])**2` for every object `x`, the dimensions `i` and the optimum (smallest cost) center `center`. It *cannot* minimize arbitrary distances (see the many many many many question on this matter here).

There are two fatal problems in your code:

- the vectorization required for *any* Cosine based approach **only works for *long* texts**, such as news articles. It does not work for Tweets or any other short text because they have too few useful tokens. As a rule of thumb, you will need 100+ words per text.
- kmeans must be applied to the *data matrix*, not to a distance matrix. It needs to compute *means* (remember, it is called k-means) of the original data. Thus, it needs the original data matrix. Also, **kmeans does not use pairwkse distances**, but only seeks the least-squares of point-to-center.

Comment: How I can pass the data matrix( string data into kmeans)!! this is text clustering, and I searched alot about it, text data need to be converted to vector, and kmeans will be applied on this vector, otherwise kmeans won't work on strings

Comment: See here http://blog.christianperone.com/2013/09/machine-learning-cosine-similarity-for-vector-space-models-part-iii/.. I followed the same method for using TFIDF and cosine approach

Comment: Yes, the data needs to be converted to a vector. But your text needs to have **100 words each** for this to work well!

Comment: This is my distance matrix for the example you gave:
 [[ 0.          0.63355318  1.        ]
 [ 0.63355318  0.          1.        ]
 [ 1.          1.          0.        ]]

Comment: `tfidf_matrix` is your data matrix. What is its shape?

Comment: Which totally makes sense, and my distance matrix looks right

Comment: (3,4) is the shape

Comment: And here is the matrix,,
   (0, 3) 0.795960541568
  (0, 0) 0.605348508106
  (1, 2) 0.795960541568
  (1, 0) 0.605348508106
  (2, 1) 1.0

Comment: I was referring to your original data matrix, not the toy example. What you are interested in is non-zero values per object. This number should be at least 50 to 100 (the more the better). **Your texts are too short**.

Comment: What I can do to prevent zeros number?? I can't understand how to configure TFIDF to prevent this!! I realize that my texts are short, but that the best way I found to do text clustering, also using only cosine_similarity returned the same problem

Comment: You *need* longer texts to have *useful* values. You can't solve this by configuration. That is why I'm saying **your data cannot be clustered** (as is, unless you add *much* more data such as language models).

Comment: The shape of the original data is (5362, 1844)

Comment: doc2vec won't work either cause it needs long texts right??

Comment: you are not helping, putting my question on data science website  on hold, and not helping here either, is not gonna solve my problem!!! you keep saying my data is the problem, this is not really professional, data can vary a lot and our job to find solutions for these data types.. You said tf-idf should be used with K-means, then what I'm using there??? and I keep telling you also that it's only k-means I'm using... I used many techniques as I mentioned, but you keep complaining in your answers instead of giving potential solutions, this is My data to cluster and won't change

Comment: And I'm telling you that no parameter tweaking whatsoever will cluster your data, because it does not have clusters in the statistical sense. You have some common words in some strings, but no *clusters*. Sorry **don't shoot the messenger**. Also don't blame me for double-posting being discouraged. I have only a 1/5 vote to close on DS, so it needed 4 others that shared my opinion to close!

Comment: I'm not seeking only parameters to fix this, I'm seeking any other techniques to reach my goal.. You suggested NLP earlier which I also tried using LSA.. I posted in data science exchange where data scientists are to solve such a problem!! If this is not clustering problem, then what is it? How the goal can be achieved!?

Comment: I strongly feel it's clustering problem, the clusters I'm getting are nice except the big one, there must be something with the distance metric or such,,,

Comment: The clusters you are getting are based on a single word each, for all I can tell. E.g. `Lice`, `Tissue`, `Prolonged`. You might as well just find **words that occur more than once** but that are not stopwords. That is not a clustering result. it's a word-counting result.

Comment: You are keep saying this, in the same time, you are not suggesting any solution, whyy??

Comment: Because there is no solution. You have too little data to do more than find words in common.

Comment: Ok lets say I want to find words in common, anything to avoid this big cluster?

Comment: No. These are all the texts that have no words in common with other texts (if you increase the number of "clusters" far enough). For example `ACS`. How many texts have *anything* in common with this text? Its because of the data!